# Service won't allow traffic to pods after re-creating deployments/pods on k8s centos7 baremetal cluster: No route to host

Tags: kubernetes

Created a bare metal multiple master cluster 1.18 release:

```
NAME            STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master1   Ready    master   9d    v1.18.0
master2   Ready    master   9d    v1.18.0
master3   Ready    master   9d    v1.18.0
worker1   Ready    <none>   9d    v1.18.0
worker2   Ready    <none>   9d    v1.18.0
worker3   Ready    <none>   9d    v1.18.0
```

*kubectl create deploy la --image=linuxacademycontent/kubeserve:v1 

kubectl  scale deploy la --replica=6 

kubectl get pod*

```
curlpod                1/1     Running   0          55m
la-65776bc88f-4kp95    1/1     Running   0          42m
la-65776bc88f-7lb9f    1/1     Running   0          42m
la-65776bc88f-dgzsz    1/1     Running   0          42m
la-65776bc88f-l2hs2    1/1     Running   0          43m
la-65776bc88f-vkcts    1/1     Running   0          42m
la-65776bc88f-wkm2k    1/1     Running   0          42m
```

*kubectl expose deploy la --port=80 --target-port=80 

kubectl get svc*

```
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP   75m
la           ClusterIP   10.103.199.187   <none>        80/TCP    46m
```

*kubectl get ep*

```
kubernetes   172.31.16.67:6443                                       78m
la           10.244.1.6:80,10.244.1.7:80,10.244.2.5:80 + 3 more...   49m
```

I can verify all is working by curling from a testpod -  curlpod
*kubectl exec -it curlpod bash*

```
This is v1 pod la-65776bc88f-dgzsz
```

**Problem is if i now delete deploy (or delete all the pods), and recreate them, the service won't allow traffic to new pods**. 
Here is how to reproduce the problem. 
*kubectl delete deploy la*

```
curlpod                1/1     Running       0          71m
la-65776bc88f-4kp95    1/1     Terminating   0          58m
la-65776bc88f-7lb9f    1/1     Terminating   0          58m
la-65776bc88f-dgzsz    1/1     Terminating   0          58m
la-65776bc88f-l2hs2    1/1     Terminating   0          59m
la-65776bc88f-vkcts    1/1     Terminating   0          58m
la-65776bc88f-wkm2k    1/1     Terminating   0          58m
```

*kubectl create deploy la --image=linuxacademycontent/kubeserve:v1* 
*kubectl scale deploy la --replicas=6* 
*kubectl get pod*

```
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
curlpod                1/1     Running   0          73m
la-65776bc88f-5q7d8    1/1     Running   0          6s
la-65776bc88f-b69z2    1/1     Running   0          10s
la-65776bc88f-j2t4t    1/1     Running   0          6s
la-65776bc88f-ndxs5    1/1     Running   0          6s
la-65776bc88f-ns2gt    1/1     Running   0          6s
la-65776bc88f-vjp8x    1/1     Running   0          6s
```

All looks fine. However, service won't allow any traffic to the new pods 
*kubectl exec -it curlpod bash*

```
root@curlpod:/app# curl la
curl: (7) Failed to connect to la port 80: No route to host
root@curlpod:/app# curl 10.103.199.187   #name resolution seems fine
curl: (7) Failed to connect to la port 80: No route to host
```

I can still reach pods individually. eg la-65776bc88f-5q7d8 has IP: 10.244.5.13

```
root@test-pod:/app# curl 10.244.5.13
This is v1 pod la-65776bc88f-5q7d8
```

So I thought it was service that won't route the traffic, but I can see service has no change and all new pods are listed as endpoints for the service. 
*kubectl get svc*

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP   93m
la           ClusterIP   10.103.199.187   <none>        80/TCP    64m
```

*kubectl get ep*

```
NAME         ENDPOINTS                                               AGE
kubernetes   172.31.16.67:6443                                       93m
la           10.244.5.13,10.244.1.9:80,10.244.2.7:80 + 3 more...   64m
```

Somewhere something is blocking the traffic from service to new pods. 

Now, if we restart the svc, the problem will go away!! 
*kubectl delete svc la* 
service "la" deleted

*kubectl expose deploy la --port=80 --target-port=80* 
service/la exposed

*kubectl get svc*

```
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   108m
la           ClusterIP   10.96.124.200   <none>        80/TCP    71s
```

*kubectl exec -it curlpod bash*

```
This is v1 pod la-65776bc88f-z24qn
```

Tried a few alternative, such as use yaml to create deployment, service, same problem. 
Also tried using kubectl scale to scale down and up. However I create new pod in the deployment, the traffic from service to pod would always be blocked.

Any help or suggestion welcome!

Add Flannel log

```
kubectl logs --namespace kube-system kube-flannel-ds-amd64-tbglf
I0423 15:15:52.311421       1 main.go:518] Determining IP address of default interface
I0423 15:15:52.312644       1 main.go:531] Using interface with name eth0 and address 10.30.193.13
I0423 15:15:52.312669       1 main.go:548] Defaulting external address to interface address (10.30.193.13)
W0423 15:15:52.312689       1 client_config.go:517] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0423 15:15:52.323517       1 kube.go:119] Waiting 10m0s for node controller to sync
I0423 15:15:52.324491       1 kube.go:306] Starting kube subnet manager
I0423 15:15:53.323919       1 kube.go:126] Node controller sync successful
I0423 15:15:53.323976       1 main.go:246] Created subnet manager: Kubernetes Subnet Manager - uk02sybk8smp3
I0423 15:15:53.323983       1 main.go:249] Installing signal handlers
I0423 15:15:53.324084       1 main.go:390] Found network config - Backend type: vxlan
I0423 15:15:53.324176       1 vxlan.go:121] VXLAN config: VNI=1 Port=0 GBP=false Learning=false DirectRouting=false
I0423 15:15:53.365832       1 main.go:355] Current network or subnet (10.244.0.0/16, 10.244.2.0/24) is not equal to previous one (0.0.0.0/0, 0.0.0.0/0), trying to recycle old iptables rules
I0423 15:15:53.367815       1 iptables.go:167] Deleting iptables rule: -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j RETURN
I0423 15:15:53.409089       1 iptables.go:167] Deleting iptables rule: -s 0.0.0.0/0 ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j MASQUERADE --random-fully
I0423 15:15:53.410118       1 iptables.go:167] Deleting iptables rule: ! -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j RETURN
I0423 15:15:53.411017       1 iptables.go:167] Deleting iptables rule: ! -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j MASQUERADE --random-fully
I0423 15:15:53.412076       1 main.go:305] Setting up masking rules
I0423 15:15:53.412916       1 main.go:313] Changing default FORWARD chain policy to ACCEPT
I0423 15:15:53.412999       1 main.go:321] Wrote subnet file to /run/flannel/subnet.env
I0423 15:15:53.413009       1 main.go:325] Running backend.
I0423 15:15:53.413017       1 main.go:343] Waiting for all goroutines to exit
I0423 15:15:53.413038       1 vxlan_network.go:60] watching for new subnet leases
I0423 15:15:53.510136       1 iptables.go:145] Some iptables rules are missing; deleting and recreating rules
I0423 15:15:53.510158       1 iptables.go:167] Deleting iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j RETURN
I0423 15:15:53.510293       1 iptables.go:145] Some iptables rules are missing; deleting and recreating rules
I0423 15:15:53.510301       1 iptables.go:167] Deleting iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
I0423 15:15:53.511096       1 iptables.go:167] Deleting iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/16 ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j MASQUERADE --random-fully
I0423 15:15:53.512091       1 iptables.go:167] Deleting iptables rule: ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.244.2.0/24 -j RETURN
I0423 15:15:53.512206       1 iptables.go:167] Deleting iptables rule: -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
I0423 15:15:53.512998       1 iptables.go:167] Deleting iptables rule: ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE --random-fully
I0423 15:15:53.513970       1 iptables.go:155] Adding iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j RETURN
I0423 15:15:53.609595       1 iptables.go:155] Adding iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
I0423 15:15:53.612312       1 iptables.go:155] Adding iptables rule: -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
I0423 15:15:53.613132       1 iptables.go:155] Adding iptables rule: -s 10.244.0.0/16 ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j MASQUERADE --random-fully
I0423 15:15:53.710527       1 iptables.go:155] Adding iptables rule: ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.244.2.0/24 -j RETURN
I0423 15:15:53.712938       1 iptables.go:155] Adding iptables rule: ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE --random-fully
```

kube-proxy is flooded with

```
E0504 08:25:36.251542       1 proxier.go:1533] Failed to sync endpoint for service: 10.30.218.46:30080/TCP, err: parseIP Error ip=[10 244 5 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
E0504 08:25:36.251632       1 proxier.go:1950] Failed to list IPVS destinations, error: parseIP Error ip=[10 244 5 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: what is the cni plugin you are using? share logs from cni pods  and kube proxy pods

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I've added flannel log and kube-proxy log. seems kube-proxy is not healthy.